# got this error when I try to map the props from my App.js to my Coins.jsx component (react)

Tags: reactjs, cryptography

[image]

got this error when I try to map the props from my App.js to my Coins.jsx component (react)got this error when I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you map over `coins` you get each `coin` so I've renamed coins to coin. Here is the concise version of what you're doing:

```
props.coins.map(coin => <CoinItem coins={coin}/>)
```

The issue is that you're using curly braces instead of parentheses.

```
props.coins.map(coin => {
  return ( // <--- paren not curly
    <CoinItem coins={coin}/>
  )
})
```

Comment: I see.. thanks man

Comment: @JoshuaBiong You can accept the answer (click checkmark to make it green) if the answer solves your question.